# How to inherit view inheritance

Tags: vue.js

Template:

```html
<div id="adult" class="content-tab">  
   <progress class="progress is-primary" value="{{parentData.rate_part}}" max="1">1%</progress>
</div>
```

Error:

> error: value="{{parentData.rate_adult}}": Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of <div id="{{ val }}">, use <div :id="val">.

I want to put the inherited `rate_part` value into `value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need `{{ }}` scope in element attribute. Use `:value="parentData.rate_part"` or `v-model="parentData.rate_part"` ..